# My new little friend

Tags: cipher, visual

A few days ago a new little friend became part of our family.
I asked him to introduce himself and he left this message for you:

[image]

Who is my new friend??

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your new friend is..

> [A very good boy](https://pasteboard.co/Hcay28A.jpg)

Explanation:

> The entire empty row on the top and the amount of rows made me believe it's a binary encoded text. Parsing it gives us
> `01101010 01110110 01110110 01110010 01110101 00111010 00101111 00101111 01110010 01100011 01110101 01110110 01100111 01100100 01110001 01100011 01110100 01100110 00101110 01100101 01110001 00101111 01001010 01100101 01100011 01100001 00110010 00111000 01000011 00101110 01101100 01110010 01101001`

Which translates to

> `jvvru://rcuvgdqctf.eq/Jeca28C.lri`
>
>   This definitely looks like an url, with the first 5 letters translating to `https://`. Rotating the letters we get -2, which returns..
>
>  `https://pasteboard.co/Hcay28A.jpg`
>
>  Which brings us to the fact that your [new friend](https://pasteboard.co/Hcay28A.jpg) is an extremely precious boy :) Make sure you give him lots of pats!

Comment: httpu:/pauteboard.co/ so maybe double-check? :-)

Comment: Close, just some letters to replace in the URL ;) (he's cute btw)

Comment: @Bass yep, definitely expected some mistakes here and there. This visualization is _extremely_ bad for showing 0s when they are surrounded by 1s :P

Comment: the errors may be in the puzzle itself, by the looks of it, or maybe the "font" just so unreadable..

Comment: Nah, i double checked and got the solution. Fun little exercise :P

Comment: I'll give you six to one odds that this puzzle looked ok and perfectly readable, and then the image was scaled. In the original, the lines between two squares were very likely the only double-width ones, but in the scaled one, the line widths are more or less random.

Comment: @votbear It's correct!! Very good job man!  :)