# Aki's favorite game

Tags: cipher, visual, language

After introducing you to my new little friend [Aki](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62167/my-new-little-friend), it's time to reveal what his favorite game is!

[image]

What is the new hobby of the little Aki?

Hint 1:

> The weight of each letter is very relevant...

Hint 2:

> Blue = 0 
>  Orange = 1

Hint 3:

> [image]
> Remember, the letters have a [value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_numerals)

Comment: has this really not gotten any answers or comments? too hard?? lol

Comment: @L_Church no, it's not very difficult :)
It is only necessary to solve step by step.

Comment: well it is clearly binary from the 0 and 1 and the weight i think is how some of the letters have more than one mention like beta shows up 4 times but alpha turns up only once

Comment: @L_Church no sorry, you're on the wrong path ;) 0 and 1 are not binary in this case and the weight does not depend on the number of occurrences. Please search "Greek alphabet" on Google ;)

Comment: :C see is hard lol

Comment: @L_Church Hint: you do not have to know the Greek to solve!! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Aki’s favorite game is

> **playing with your shoe!**

The grid under each letter represents a decimal number as shown in hint 3, the first and second numbers being 104 and 232 respectively. Then dividing each of those numbers by its above number represented by the Greek letter in the Byzantine numeral system we have the following decimal numbers.

> 104 116 116 112 115 58 47 47 119 119 119 46 121 111 117 116 117 98 101 46 99 111 109 47 119 97 116 99 104 63 118 61 101 89 100 108 78 84 84 114 73 83 65

Converting this to text gives

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eYdlNTTrISA

where we find the good boy doing what he loves.

Comment: Very good job man!! ;)